# Should i be worried of these permissions from an app?

Tags: applications, settings, permissions

I was going to download an app ( not giving its proper name because there are many other apps who wants same permissions) but when i was looking for what  'app permissions' it needed. I saw permissions 'camera' , 'identity' , 'send sticky broadcast' and 'request install packages'.

Why an app actually needed to take permission of camera when there is no need of camera anyhow within the app ?
And what are those settings permissions under *other* section ?

[image]

Comment: You can always ask the developer (E-mail at bottom of play listing)why they explicitly need a permission. They may or may-not answer though.

Comment: Without knowing what the app is about, it's hard to tell. Camera e.g. is not only for taking photos – but also used to scan barcodes, and to control the flash light.

Comment: No, there is no use of Camera at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have found, a Sticky Broadcast is a broadcast from an application that stays hanging around after it has been dealt with. It helps for things like battery level. I found this [here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/android-sticky-broadcast-52149.html).

As for Request Install Packages, it

> Allows an application to request installing packages

Source: [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES)

As for why an app would need permissions to something that it seems like it has no business using, there could be a few explanations. I am a developer and can say that there might be something in the API for Camera that is used, but the actual camera is not. Without know what app you are wanting, one could not say definitively.

Comment: Hey it is confusing me that there are all types of permissions written in the blog you attached. Could you please deliver me 'request install packages' means will app ask me before pushing any packages or updates to the device ?

Comment: @JohnMasamune It should show an installation dialog when it tries to install an app unless the developer went around that and installs the package silently.

Comment: Yeah that's my reason to ask this question that if one can make changes to installed apps silently.